# Is it possible to increment/initialize a variable inside 'generate' in verilog?

Tags: parameters, verilog, increment

I have a doubt in the `generate`, my code is:

```
parameter m=1;

generate 
 for(i=0; i<m; i=i+1) :loopstart
 begin
  statements;
 end
endgenerate
```

Inside this loop, **m should be 2^0, 2^1, 2^2, and so on**. Since
exponentiation is not supported, I thought of initializing m and then
multiplying it by 2 on each iteration.

I have a few questions:

Is it possible to use `m << 1` inside the generate in some way (since this is the same as 
multiplying by 2)? If I do that, it results in an error.

I referred to Samir Palnitkar's book, which says that always statement works inside a generate, so I tried:

```
always @(m)
 m <= m*2; // (or m << 1)
```

This doesn't work. I realize it can't be done because `m` is a parameter and not a variable.

If what I think is right, it can't be done with `genvar` either, since a `genvar` can't be initialized.

Is there an alternative?

Answer (score 1):

The question seem to have been created because exponentials are not supported. They are :

```
2**0 => 1
2**1 => 2
2**2 => 4
```

NB:

```
always @(m)
 m <= m*2; // (or m << 1)
```

This is wrong for a few reasons

1. Do not use `<=` in combinatorial blocks
2. In the above expression m defines itself and re-triggers the loop.

I would also avoid named sensitivity lists and use `always @*` to avoid hardware simulation mismatches from incomplete sensitivity lists.

parameters and localparams are for defining constants, if they are not constant use something else like a logic or integer type.

```
logic [31:0] m = 0;
logic [31:0] power_two_m;
always @* begin
  power_two_m = 2**m;
  power_two_m = 1 << m;
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead `i++` use `i=i+1`

And.. forget C.

Comment: on no :( i typed i++ here by mistake. i have entered it correctly in the program..

Comment: I have solved it.. i took m in another loop above i loop and did m=m*2, thanks all :)

Comment: @Nandhini please post an answer describing how you resolved the problem

Comment: @ Andy : I had to do m=2^j for j=0,1,2 and so on inside a for loop inside 'generate' such that m=1,2,4,.... Instead what i did was that i removed j from the loop and just took the variable m inside the for loop and wrote for(m=1;condition;m=m*2). this way it works.